# Python program to returns how far away letters are in a string

Tags: python

Im having some problems with this code i made. 
Here are the parameters

Given a word, find the minimum width of a "mop" required to erase each of the letters.

Example

For word = "abacaba", the output should be
theJanitor(word) = [7, 5, 1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0] (26 elements altogether).

```
def theJanitor(word):

    left = [0] * 26
    right = [0] * 26
    was = [0] * 26
    for i in range(26):
        left.append(0)
        right.append(0)
        was.append(False)

    for i in range(len(word)):
        c = ord(word[i]) - ord('a')
        if was[c]:
            left[c] = i
            was[c] = True
        right[c] = i

    ans = []
    for i in range(26):
        ans.append(right[i] - left[i] + 1 if was[i] else 0)
    return ans
```

Comment: please fix indentation in the code

Comment: Don't you mean `theJanitor(word) = [6, 5, 1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0]`, since the last `'a'` is at index 6?

Answer (score 1):

Find the first and last occurence of each letter

```
for letter in 'abc...':
    left_index = text.find(letter)
    right_index = text.rfind(letter)
    mop_size = right_index - left_index + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a bit different and cleaner approach then your original code:

```
def theJanitor(word):
    let = sorted(set(word))
    mop_len = [word.rfind(c) - word.find(c) + 1 for c in let]
    mop_len += [0]*(26-len(mop_len))

    return mop_len
```

Using `set(word)` the program finds all unique letters in each word sorted in alphabetical order. For each letter it computes the mop width from the first and last index of occurrence. In the last line the array with mop widths is padded with zeros to the target length of 26.

In case you want your letters appearing in order of occurrence use this instead of the `set` approach,

```
let = [x for i, x in enumerate(word) if x not in word[0:i]]
```

Comment: When I run this, the results are out of order.

Answer (score 0):

Using `word.find()` as suggested by @blue_note seems like the easiest way to do this, but here's a "lower level" version in the spirit of the original code:

```
def janitor(word):
    left = [None] * 26
    right = [None] * 26
    widths = []

    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        k = ord(c) - ord('a')
        if left[k] is None:
            left[k] = i
        right[k] = i

    for k in range(26):
        if left[k] is None:
            width = 0
        else:
            width = right[k] - left[k] + 1
        widths.append(width)

    return widths
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using both `rfind` and `find`

```
import string
def janitor(word):
    alphabets = string.ascii_lowercase
    result = [0]*26
    for i in word:
        index = alphabets.find(i)
        if word.rfind(i) < 0:
            result[index] = 0
        else:
            result[index]=word.rfind(i) - word.find(i) + 1
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    janitor('abacaba')
```

Output:

```
[7, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```